# OpenSSL SMIME output to stdout PHP exec command

Tags: php, bash, openssl, exec, smime

I have the following running code on PHP7.

```
$command = "openssl smime -verify -inform DER -in ".$path."  -noverify -out ".PATH_XML_EXTRACT.$filename_output;
exec( $command, $output, $return_var );
```

The openssl command creates the file properly. Can I avoid to store the message content to the output file? I want to get the message as a string (for example in the $output variable) and managing the flow in memory (no writing on the disk).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `-text` instead of `-out filename`, or use the OpenSSL extension directly instead of calling out to the shell. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Comment: The option -text doesn’t work and the extension require to use temp files, so I’ll be on the starting point. I would avoid to use the storage...